# Silent print with Foxit Reader from process opens GUI

Tags: c#, command-line, printing, process, foxit-reader

I'm having trouble with printing a PDF through Foxit Reader.. The problem is not that it's not printing, but that the **GUI is loaded** when trying to do so.. I would like the printing to just happen in the background...

Everything I read so far suggests that the code below is supposed to actually print in the background, yet for every print job, the Foxit GUI pops open... The GUI also closes after printing, but I don't want it to open in the first place. I am executing the code below from a Console application that hosts a WCF service if that would be important...

```
        ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psInfo.FileName = FoxitReaderLocation;
        psInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"",
            fileLocation,
            printerName);
        psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process process = Process.Start(psInfo);
        process.WaitForExit(10000);
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            process.Kill();
            process.Dispose();
        }
```

Printing with `/p "filelocation"`also works with the default printer, but the same problem with the GUI occurs.
Doing this with Adobe Reader occurs silently, but doesn't print half of my files (but then again, the command line interface of Adobe Reader is not officially supported, so please don't suggest to use Adobe Reader)

Sources:

- [Article that describes what i want, but isn't as silent as desired](http://www.brooksnet.com/content/how-print-pdf-files-command-line-windows-printer)
- [Command line switches for the foxit command line interface](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Foxit)
- [Link to foxit manual](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/reader/en_us/FoxitReader70_Manual.pdf#page=199)
- [Similar SO question, but pretty Matlab specific, answers didn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115080/there-is-any-way-to-run-processes-in-the-background)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is by design of the the new version of Foxit Reader.

Removing the latest version downloaded from official site and install older version (*6.2.3*) from [Old Apps](http://www.oldapps.com/foxit_reader.php).
The process terminated immediately after printing.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem, but got fixed when I rearranged the arguments int he string:

```
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" \"{0}\" /t  \"{1}\"",
      reportFullPath,
      printerName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the WindowStyle property, most windowed applications listen to it:

```
psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Additionally, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) states the CreateNoWindow is n̲o̲t̲ compatible with UseShellExecute, so you should probably turn that off:

```
psInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //Using ShellExecute messes stuff up
```

However, CreateNoWindow actually specifies whether or not to use the existing console window for console apps,<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5094079/5302626)</sup> and can be left unspecified as it has no effect on the start of GUI apps.

Comment: Maybe you missed in the question, but WindowStyle is already set.. And setting UseShellExecute made no difference.. Thanks for thinking with me though!